# How can I search for a string in the gitweb interface of a git repository?

Tags: git, gitweb

I would like to search for `kill` in the  gitweb  interface of [the repository of Bash](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=bash.git) .

In that link, I typed `kill` on the top right input box, and leave `commit`selected on the left. But the search result is empty, [which is incorrect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492477/674).

So how can I search for a string in the gitweb interface of a Git repository?

Comment: Git clone the repo and git grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When selecting `commit` you will search for the character sequence `kill` in the commit message. 
To find `kill` in the source code you should select `grep`.

Comment: Thanks. I'd appreciate if you could consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54267252/is-gitweb-a-web-application-or-the-client-of-a-web-application