# Is gitweb a web application or the client of a web application?

Tags: git, web-applications

I am confused about the terms of web interfaces and web applications.

1. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitweb#_webserver_configuration says

   > This section explains how to configure some common webservers to run gitweb.

   Does that imply that `gitweb` is a web application which can only be
   run on a web server? Is `gitweb` a web application in the same sense
   as a web application written in Java servelet and run on Tomcat?
2. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitweb#_webserver_configuration says

   > gitweb is a Git web interface (web frontend to Git repositories)

   *Git Pocket Guide* says

   > Git comes with a web-based repository browser called “gitweb.”

   Does a "web interface" mean the client of a web application?

   Does that mean gitweb is the client of a web application also called
   "gitweb"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused about the terms of web interfaces and web applications.

They're actually the same. Web applications are programs that run on web servers. They generate web interfaces. That is, they produce HTML+CSS+Javascript, and web interface is what users see in their browsers.

> 1… gitweb is a web application which can only be run on a web server? Is gitweb a web application in the same sense as a web application written in Java servelet and run on Tomcat?

Yes to both. `gitweb` is written in Perl, but that's a minor technical detail.

> 2… gitweb is a Git web interface (web frontend to Git repositories)
>   Git Pocket Guide says: Git comes with a web-based repository browser called “gitweb.”

It's the same `gitweb`.

> Does a "web interface" mean the client of a web application?

No. `gitweb` is a client of `git`, i.e. it takes all its information from git repositories. It presents the acquired information to users via its web interface. A user who uses `gitweb` views git repositories using a browser. (I'm afraid my answer sounds like I speak to a 3 y.o.)

> Does that mean gitweb is the client of a web application also called "gitweb"?

No, there is only one `gitweb`. It's a web application that shows git repositories.

Comment: Thanks. "gitweb is a client of git", do you mean "git" runs as a server process for serving `gitweb` process?

Comment: It simply runs `git` executable. The path to `git` binary is given at the installation time and is stored in the generated [perl code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/16a465bc018d09e9d7bbbdc5f40a7fb99c21f8ef/gitweb/gitweb.perl#L83).

Comment: Thanks. Is a CGI script in general a web application?

Comment: It's a way to run a web application on a web server. It's suitable for a small not overloaded web application.